# jQuery validation group with Has-Success appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with jquery.validate.

I've 2 forms on the same page, so im using validation group 
fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N5BYk/5/

the group validation is succeed, but i need some enhancement on the appearance:

1. whenever that's an error, need to change the color of the label too(email/password).
2. after fill in the correct input, the textbox border change to green color. (already have this css done, called 'has-success')

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="validationGroup form-group">
        <label for="Username">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Username" class="required email form-control" value="" />
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="Password" class="required form-control" value="" />
        <button id="login" class="causesValidation">submit</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="validationGroup form-group">
        <label for="Username">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="required form-control" value="" />
        <button id="Order" class="causesValidation">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
label.error {
    clear: none;
    color: Red;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate({
        onsubmit: false
    });

    $('.validationGroup .causesValidation').click(Validate);          
});

function Validate(evt) {
    var $group = $(this).parents('.validationGroup');
    var isValid = true;
    $group.find(':input').each(function (i, item) {
        if (!$(item).valid()) {
            $(this).closest('.validationGroup').addClass('has-error');
            isValid = false;
        }
    });

    if (!isValid) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: there was no need to add Twitter BooStrap in Tag.

Comment: Check this site https://control.crucial.com.au/clientarea.php    , Get proper file for same purpose https://control.crucial.com.au/templates/crucial/js/validations/jquery.validate.js

Comment: apply css for class ".valid"  . Use border color : green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin has a attribute "validClass". you can set the success class name there.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/N5BYk/10/